# Why use "like" In the question "What is a typical home like there?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I found this Question in a student book and I can't understand why not "What is a typical home there?"

Comment: Like means that you are asking for the characteristics of a typical house. Without like your question is more ambiguous; are you asking about price?

Comment: Have you looked up what "like" means in a dictionary? On this site users are expected to research their problem, and post a question only if their research fails to resolve their confusion. You might also do a search for "usage of like" on our sibling site [ell.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Like*** is, in this case, asking for the *characteristics* of a typical home - is it big, is it warm, is it a house or a flat (apartment), what sort of decoration does it have? It allows for impressions, subtler answers, and for an answer that includes several options.

Without the *like*, the question is asking for a *definition* of a typical home. It is a very *factual* question.

The difference is subtle, but noticeable. If you were trying to get an idea of what a place was like, for personal reasons or out of interest, people tend to use *like*, in my experience. If you are trying to get a more academic understanding, you would be more likely to not use *like*.